# Is there a setting to turn off macros in vi / vim

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, vi, intellij-plugin

I'm using the vi plugin in my ide (Intellij) and every now and again fat finger the '@' having inadvertantly recorded a macro.

The plugin then runs the macro and destroys the source file I'm editing and often other buffers as well.  With no recourse using the "undo" feature.

Is there some kind of setting to simply disable the macro feature of vi / vim?

And if so what is it?

Comment: You mean `nmap @ <Nop>` ?

Comment: Why is undo broken?

Comment: There is a request for canceling Macro in IDE: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1777

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to turn off vim recording for good, add `map q <Nop>` to your .ideavimrc file.

The file can be accessed right from the IDE by clicking on 'Vim' shortcut in the status bar and choosing the corresponding option.

See https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#files for more info.

[image: vim]